# How to use APDU I/O API in Eclipse

Tags: javacard, apdu, jcop

What needs to be done to run an APDU I/O API application in Eclipse? I tried first to start the Simulator and run the apdu scripts *cap-MyJavaCardApplet.script* and *create-myjavacardapplet.myjavacardapplet.MyJavaCardApplet.script*. But it did not worked.

My development environment:

1. Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (includes Incubating components)
   Version: 2023-09 (4.29.0) Build id: 20230907-1323 OS: Windows 10,
   v.10.0, x86_64 / win32 Java vendor: Eclipse Adoptium Java runtime
   version: 17.0.8.1+1 Java version: 17.0.8.1
2. Java Card Development Kit Simulator 3.1.0
3. Java Card Development Kit Tools 3.1.0